# calculating area of triangle APE

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I'm calculating the area of the triangle APE.

Given that $\vec{AP} = \vec{PE}$. My assumption is that P would represent an 'identity', for A and E, suggesting that A = E. Although, this is probably not the case.

How would I tackle this question?

The area of a triangle for ABC = $\frac{1}{2} |\vec{AB}\times \vec{AC}|$

I thought that APE would be something like: $\frac{1}{2} |\vec{AP}\times \vec{AE}|$ given that A=E, although I get 0.

What did I miss?

Given that $\vec{AP}=(3, 5, 0) - (1, 5, 2) = (2, 0, -2)$

How would I find more than one possible coordinate for E?

If a point E lies on the line $l_1$, which has the equation:

$\pmatrix{1 \\ 5 \\ 2} + \lambda \pmatrix{-5 \\ 4 \\ 3}$ Given $\lambda$ = 1, does this change the significance above?

Comment: Do you mean $\vec{AP} = \vec{PE}$ or $\lvert AP \rvert = \lvert PE \rvert$ ?

Comment: the former, I have updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{AP} = \vec{PE}$, we have a degenerate triangle.

$$\vec{AP} = \vec{PE} $$
$$\Rightarrow \vec{P}-\vec{A}=\vec{E}-\vec{P}$$
$$\Rightarrow \vec{P} = \frac{\vec{A}+\vec{E}}{2}$$

Since the direction of $\vec{AP}$, $\vec{PE}$ is same, $P$ is collinear with $A,E$ and is shown to be the midpoint of $AE$. The area is thus, zero.

Comment: I see, so If I add coordinates like the updated edit above, does this change the value of $\mathbf{E}$ relative to $\mathbf{A}$ ?

Comment: @Workaroundcode $\vec{AP} = \vec{PE}$ says there is a unique point $E$ given by $E=2P-A$ (P lies between A and E). There is no second possibility for E.

Comment: Although, wouldn't it be possible to find a coordinate position of E? How would this be calculated?

Comment: Given $A=(1,5,2)$, $P=(3,5,0)$, as mentioned in above comment, $E=2P-A=2(3,5,0)-(1,5,2)=(5,5,-2)$. $\vec{AP} = \vec{PE} \Rightarrow P-A=E-P \Rightarrow E=2P-A$.